# Safecracker How to clone entry after update to EE2.6.1

Tags: safecracker, upgrade

Before updating to latest EE version 2.6.1, setting title and url-title to new values + setting hidden input field with name "entry_id" to '' on a safecracker edit entry form would generate a clone. Now instead the new entry  simply overwrites the original one. What else is needed?

Being able to clone entries is a huge time saver, so I would really appreciate an answer on where to look to get this working again.

Comment: I've confirmed that this is a deliberate change in 2.6.1 for security issues. I don't have an answer for how to duplicate now, but it looks like it will take some php work. Hopefully someone else will have a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my workaround answer for post EE 2.6.1, not ideal, but seems to be working:

Embed the info from the entry you want to duplicate as a form within the parent SafeCracker page. Something like:

```
-----
PARENT
-----

{exp:safecracker channel="my_channel"}

    {embed="my_tpl_group/my_form" copy_from_entry_id="123"}

    <p>
        <button id="form_submit" type="submit" class="">Duplicate Program</button>
    </p>

{/exp:safecracker}


-----
EMBED
-----

{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" entry_id="{embed:copy_from_entry_id}" }

    {!-- Output the pre-filled form of the entry you are wanting to duplicate --}
    <p>
        <label for="program_number">program_number</label>
        <input type="text" name="program_number" id="program_number" value="{if program_number}{program_number}{/if}">
    </p>

    <input type="hidden" name="program_start_date" id="program_start_date" value="{if program_start_date}{program_start_date format='%F %d, %Y'}{/if}">

    .....etc.....

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: This embed method works but with Channel Form it breaks inline error reporting which I need. Am thinking maybe of trying with Stash.

Did anyone ever find a more robust method than this embed one?